# How to SpyOn function inside Function and return Fake value

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, spyon

This Question seems to be same but definitely  not duplicate.

In one of my function i am calling `this.cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, key)`

this `cordovafile.readAsArrayBuffer()` reads data from ipad File storage, but in Unit test  i cant do that since it runs in Browsers, so i am using SpyOn to get fake value, i am getting difficulties to do that.

can some one help me below is the Function

```
    private getTimesheetByKey(key: TIMESHEET_KEYS): Observable<TimesheetModel> {
        let timesheet: TimesheetModel;

        return from(
            this.cordovaFile
                .readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, key)
                .then(compressedConfirmation => {
                    const start = moment();
                    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(compressedConfirmation);
                    const jsonTimeSheet = this.LZString.decompressFromUint8Array(uint8Array);

                    timesheet = new TimesheetModelFromJson(<JsonTimesheetModel>(
                        JSON.parse(jsonTimeSheet)
                    ));
                    this.saveTimesheetByKey(key, timesheet);
                    return timesheet;
                })
                .catch((error: Error) => {})
        );
    }
```

and This is how the Unit Test what i am trying to write, I dont know exactly how to SpyOn `this.cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, key)` and returns value

```
it('should save the Timesheet to file storage', () => {
        spyOn(LocalStorageTimesheetService, 'getTimesheetByKey')
            .and.callThrough(cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer())
            .and.returnValue(timesheet);

        expect(timesheet).toEqual();
    });
```

`this.cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer()` should **return fake value** something like below

```
timesheet = {
            startOfWork: '2019-07-02T02:00:00.000Z',
            notifications: [],
            additionalExpenses: [],
            manualTimesheetEntries: [],
            endOfWork: undefined,
            isSubmitted: false,
            attendanceType: 'FREE',
        };
```

Comment: I hope my answer will help you in more ways than one. Let me know if you need clarificaiton

Comment: Yes, It worked !!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think `spyOn(LocalStorageTimesheetService, 'getTimesheetByKey')` will work because `getTimesheetByKey` is a private function. Make it `public`  first.

Also, by `spying` the `readAsArrayBuffer`, you will be able to control the outcome which is **`compressedConfirmation`** and not `timesheet`. `timesheet` is calculated after performing `new Uint8Array()` **etc etc**  operations over `compressedConfirmation`

If you are worried about just checking if the value is saved when we call `getTimesheetByKey` then you can write it like:

```
it('should call "saveTimesheetByKey()" when getTimesheetByKey() is called', () => {
    const compressedConfirmationMock = 'some_val'; // expected Mock value of compressedConfirmation
    spyOn(LocalStorageTimesheetService.cordovaFile, 'readAsArrayBuffer').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(compressedConfirmationMock));
    spyOn( LocalStorageTimesheetService, 'saveTimesheetByKey').and.callThrough();
    LocalStorageTimesheetService.getTimesheetByKey(SOME_VAL_OF_TYPE_TIMESHEET_KEYS);
    expect(LocalStorageTimesheetService.saveTimesheetByKey).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


it('should save the Timesheet to file storage using saveTimesheetByKey()', () => {
    // here unit test the logic of saveTimesheetByKey() function 
    // which is actually saving the data. 
})


it('should perform some logic where getTimesheetByKey() is called', () => {
   // improve the "it" statement. 
   spyOn(LocalStorageTimesheetService, 'getTimesheetByKey')
        .and.returnValue(of({
            startOfWork: '2019-07-02T02:00:00.000Z',
            notifications: [],
            additionalExpenses: [],
            manualTimesheetEntries: [],
            endOfWork: undefined,
            isSubmitted: false,
            attendanceType: 'FREE',
        }));
   // and here write unit test that function which is using value of `timesheet` returned by calling "getTimesheetByKey()"
   //  expect block here
})
```

Please note the way I have broken your unit test logic to 3 different blocks. Unit test should be more isolated tests and should be written on granular level of function logic.

Comment: Yes, Thank You, I have added this by changing little bit, It worked !!!

Comment: @VikasKalapur Great. Please mark it as an answer as well :)